# Comparing/matching Strings in java

Tags: java, string

I'm dealing with a large database which have two columns. The first column `id` is a `long` while second column `name` is a `String`. `name` is the name of a person with corresponding id. So, I wish to compare the `name` of row with `name` of other rows.

```
John Carter
john Carter
Carter
jo car
Willam Carter
C William
Carter j.
```

All these `name`s in rows should provide matches. If possible it would be great to have the percentage/ratio of match. Is there any java library/snippet that can do this? I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: How could "John" ever match "William Carter"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorrry,  my bad.

Comment: And similarly, "C. William" and "john carter"?

Comment: OliCharlesworth Corrected that, but you get the idea, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library could be interesting for you: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/

It provides different similarity measures for Strings.

From their SourceForge page:

> SimMetrics is a Similarity Metric Library, e.g. from edit distance's
>   (Levenshtein, Gotoh, Jaro etc) to other metrics, (e.g Soundex,
>   Chapman).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you'll be interested in the [Levenshtein algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for computing string distances. You can find a Java implementation [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the paper ['A Comparison of String Distance Metrics for Name-Matching Tasks'](http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/doc/iiweb03.pdf) of [William W. Cohen](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wcohen/) et al. The paper compares several string distance metrics.

They also implemented the most of them within the [SecondString project](http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/). It is a "open-source Java-based package of approximate string-matching techniques" so you could easily compare the different metrics to evaluate which of them fits your requirements.

If you just need to match names - **Jaro-Winkler** is a good choice, which is also implemented within the [SecondString](http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/) package.

If you have all your names in a database, it may makes sense to implement the similarity measure as stored procedure to avoid fetching all the data to compare them using java. So you could use queries like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name, sim(t1.name, t2.name) FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE sim(t1.name, t2.name) > 0.8
```