# If then else logic not picking up results from String targetID = ((Node) targetId.item(0)).getNodeValue();

Tags: java, soap

I'm using the results from `String targetID = ((Node) targetId.item(0)).getNodeValue()` in some if logic: `if (targetID == "OK")` and `else if (targetID == "UNKNOWN_USER")`, but both comparisons fail. I print out `targetID` and it displays correctly and displays as `java.lang.String`, so what am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing/matching Strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970889/comparing-matching-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Use `equals()` and not `==` for string comparison:

```
if (targetID.equals("OK")) { ... }
```

etc.

`s1 == s2` compares *references*, which is rarely what you want when comparing strings.